# Bounce Game in Tkinter. Gives Error saying "can't invoke "update" command: application has been destroyed"

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.3

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, canvas, paddle, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.paddle = paddle

        self.id = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 25, 25, fill=color)

        starts = [-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3]
        random.shuffle(starts)

        self.x = starts[0]
        self.y = -3
        self.canvas_height = canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas_width = canvas.winfo_width()

        self.is_hitting_bottom = False

        canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)

        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)

        if pos[1] <= 0:
            self.y = 1

        if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
            # self.y = -1
            self.is_hitting_bottom = True

        if self.hit_top_paddle(pos) == True:
            self.y = -3

        if self.hit_bottom_paddle(pos) == True:
            self.y = 1

        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 3

        if pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = -3

    def hit_top_paddle(self, pos):
        paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.id)
        if pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]:
            if pos[3] >= paddle_pos[1] and pos[3] <= paddle_pos[3]:
                return True

            return False

    def hit_bottom_paddle(self, pos):
            paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.id)
            if pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]:
                if pos[1] >= paddle_pos[1] and pos[1] <= paddle_pos[3]:
                        return True

            return False

class Paddle:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 10, fill=color)

        self.x = 0
        self.canvas_width = canvas.winfo_width()

        canvas.move(self.id, 200, 300)

        canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', self.move_left)
        canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', self.move_right)

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, 0)

        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)

        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 0

        if pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = 0

    def move_left(self, event):
        self.x = -2

    def move_right(self, event):
        self.x = 2

tk = Tk()
tk.title('Game')
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=550, height=400, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
tk.update()

paddle = Paddle(canvas, 'blue')
ball = Ball(canvas, paddle, 'red')

while 1:
    if ball.is_hitting_bottom == False:
        ball.draw()
        paddle.draw()

    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

After running this, it gives the following error:

```
self.tk.call('update', 'idletasks')
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "update" command:  application has been destroyed
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.  The game plays fine for me.  That error only comes when I close the window, which is perfectly expected since, in doing so, I destroy the application.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to stop doing the `while` loop, and instead take advantage of tkinter's event loop.

For example:

```
def draw_frame():
    '''Draws a new frame every N milliseconds'''
    ball.draw()
    paddle.draw()
    root.after(10, draw_frame)

# draw the first frame once the GUI starts up
after_idle(draw_frame)

# start the event loop
root.mainloop()
```

You can adjust the speed of your program by changing the first argument to `after`.